# C# program Out of memory

Tags: c#, object, out-of-memory

I have a program which runs out of memory. I don't understand why as I set the `object = null` when it has been "handled".

```
foreach (DataRow theRow in thisDataSet.Tables["Collection"].Rows)
{
    LS_BatchAID = Convert.ToString(theRow["BatchAID"]);
    LS_Batch = Convert.ToString(theRow["Batch"]);
    LS_ID = Convert.ToString(theRow["ID"]);
    CL_Batch Batch = new CL_Batch(LS_BatchAID, LS_ID, LS_Batch);
    Batch = null;
}

thisConnection.Close();
```

I get this error: System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
While running the program and watching taskmanager, I can watch memory consumption rise linearly in correspondence with the number of iterations of the code.

How am I supposed to make a program that doesn't increase memory consumption/dump?

```
CL_Batch:

class CL_Batch
    {
        private string BatchAID;
        private string ID;
        private string Batch;
        private string pathPDF;
        private string pathCPR;
        private string pathLog;
        private string DateXMLGenerated;

        private string[] IDType; 
        private string[,] IDTypes;
        private string[] Files;
        private DateTime Dates;
        private byte[] pdfContent;
        private string XMLContent;
        private string[] RefNbr;

        public CL_Batch(string IV_BatchAID, string IV_ID, string IV_Batch)
        {
            this.Dates = DateTime.Now;

            this.DatoXMLGenerated = "" + Dato.Date.Year.ToString() + "-" + BuildNumber(true, 2, Dato.Date.Month.ToString()) + "-" + BuildNumber(true, 2, Dato.Date.Day.ToString()) + "";
            this.BatchAID = IV_BatchAID;
            this.ID = IV_ID;
            this.Batch = IV_Batch;
            this.pathPDF = @"C:\path\TempFiles\path\" + this.ID + ".Pdf";
            this.pathCPR = @"C:\path\TempFiles\";
            this.pathLog = @"C:\path\Log\" + this.Batch + ".txt";

            setRefnbr();

                // Set array with mappings of ID between partners.
                setLegitimationsTyper();

                // ensure log is available ( [NameOfLog] ).
                prepareLog();

                // Find all files for archive.
                getFileNames();

                // Move files C:\path\TempFiles\
                if (this.getFiles() == true)
                {
                    // Create PDF's. 
                    makePDF();

                    // Insert PDF's in database.
                    insertPDF();

                    // Create XML files.
                    makeXML();

                    // Insertt XML in database.
                    insertXML();

                }



        public string getBatchAID()
        {
            return this.BatchAID;
        }

        public string getID()
        {
            return this.ID;
        }

        public string getBatch()
        {
            return this.Batch;
        }

        public string getIDTyper(string IV_Code, bool kode)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= this.IDTypes.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                if (this.IDTypes[i, 0] == IV_Kode)
                {
                    if (Code == true)
                    {
                        return this.LegitimationsTyper[i, 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return this.LegitimationsTyper[i, 2];
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
}
```

/******************************************/

/** UPDATE #1 **************************/

Fair enough! Misuse of the constructor. I get the point - But:
What is the problem really?

If I do as I already has done versus this example:

```
CL_Batch Batch = new CL_Batch(LS_BatchAID, LS_ID, LS_Batch);

Batch.setRefnbr();
Batch.setIDTypes();
Batch.prepareLog();
Batch.getFileNames();
Batch.makePDF();
Batch.insertPDF();
Batch.makeXML();
Batch.insertXML();
Batch = null;
```

Then what is the real difference?
If it was to different ways to add a couple of numbers, then it would end up with the same instructions.

```
First program:
xor ax, ax
mov ax, 10
add ax, 10

Second program:
xor ax, ax
mov ax, 10
add ax, 10
```

The way I see it there is no difference in the end ( I recon that I misuse the concept of oop, but the endproduct is the same - I expect)

Please advice me regarding my delusion.

Thanks in advance.
/** UPDATE #1                              /
/******************************************/

Comment: What is CL_Batch?

Comment: Reducing your snippet to a `foreach` isn't a way of minimizing noise to us - it would be better if you just reduced noise in the the entire class and showed us this reduced class - you never know it may be something that is not in your foreach loop

Comment: I reckon your issue could be around the amount of strings in your memory, but you will need to profile this to find the actual answer, use dotMemory or similar

Comment: What does the constructor of CL_Batch? And why do you null the object you just created? That smells like a constructor which is being abused.

Comment: Make sure you're employing `using` constructs instead of manually handling closing of connections, statements, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're going to have to re-think your design, pretty much from the ground up.  Clearly, the object is persistent for some other reason, such that merely setting the variable to `null` does not make it a candidate to be reaped by the garbage-collector.  If, as I suspect, this object represents "a batch process," there are rather-strict limits of how many of these you can actually have at one time without the system having a fatal case of ... *ahh* ... constipation.  So, instead of trying to create objects in a loop, you're going to need some kind of a queue ...

Comment: This is C# not C.  And pretty much everything you have is wrong.

Comment: We're still missing the relevant code. The constructor is calling methods that aren't included. The problem could be *anything*. But you shouldn't have behavior that "does something" in your constructor. It's evident that you do because you're creating the object then setting it to null, which suggests that just creating the object causes something to happen. We should create an object and then do something with the object. The constructor itself shouldn't be where the class's behavior is.

Comment: @BugFinder Hereby CL_Batch is added.

Comment: @CallumLinington Hereby reduced class is added.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid My intension was to clear the object for every row in the database (actually to reduce memory consumption). Not a good way, then please guide me to best practice on this kind of matter.

Comment: You can start by telling us what you are trying to do instead of how you are doing it.

Comment: @ManoDestra I believe I am employing using.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Can you guide me to a good approach?

Comment: @MatthewWhited Please guide me of how to.

Comment: With all respect, try to learn the basics on Object Orientated Programming. The constructor should be used to construct an object, not execute all kinds of code. This does not only render your created object useless, it also makes it unusable for another use case.

Comment: I can't dumpster-dive into code-writing right now.  Basically, though, you're going to need to process that list (and *not* in your constructor!) one element at a time.  Figure out how many of these things you can actually run at one time.  Create that many, and give each one work to do.  Then, you must have a way to be notified that one of them has finished its work, so that you can give it more work to do.  In this way, the to-do list is gradually consumed, but the number of objects remains fixed.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Well I thought that using the object as a container would be a fine approach. Apparently this is wrong. But then how should I "pack" the stuff and ensure it is cleared from memory? Each batch is different in size.
Im making a mental note about your advice regarding my mis/-use of the object / constructor. Can you help me?

Comment: You are not using the object as a container at all because the object is cleared before it is used. Just create the object and put in the values it should have. Then execute the methods you need to execute on the instance you created. [This](https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=c%23+design+patterns) and [this](https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how+to+learn+oop+c%23) is a good start.

Comment: Don't do all that PDF/XML creation stuff during the database reads. Get all your basic model objects from the database, THEN generate PDFs from those model objects using a well defined method. And ensure that you use using constructs where required there too in that PDF generation code.

Comment: @LarsHansen You can't be employing using constructs given that you are manually closing your connection. And you'll need to check your PDF and XML code for potentially using wrappers too.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Please refer to update #1.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Please refer to update #1.

Comment: @ManoDestra Please refer to update #1.

Comment: a) You're potentially racking up a lot of memory by not using using constructs for everything that needs to be closed and freed up in terms of resources. And you are muddying the waters by doing everything at once. Get all your beans back first based on your database reads, then proceed to do any processing thereafter with your beans. That way, you'll be able to see easily what's causing the error, whether it's the database reads, or the file manipulation stuff. Do each thing separately. Divide your concerns sensibly. It will make your life and debugging far simpler.

Comment: You haven't posted the code for any of the PDF or XML methods, so I can't say for certain, but the issue almost certainly lies in there, if you are not closing something appropriately and looping over a collection whilst doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I have disagreed with the proposals regarding bad constructor code, then I have to acknowledge that it made a difference and that the code works as intended after removing code from the constructor.
If anyone has a good explanation for me then I would like to hear it.
Is there anyway I can give you guys (BugFinder,
Callum Linington,
Mixxiphoid,
ManoDestra,
Mike Robinson,
Matthew Whited,
Scott Hannen) credit for the solution?

This is the code that works:

```
 foreach (DataRow theRow in thisDataSet.Tables["Collection"].Rows)
 {
  LS_BatchAID = Convert.ToString(theRow["BatchAID"]);
  LS_Batch = Convert.ToString(theRow["Batch"]);
  LS_ID = Convert.ToString(theRow["ID"]);
  CL_Batch Batch = new CL_Batch(LS_BatchAID, LS_ID, LS_Batch);
  Batch.setRefnbr();
  Batch.setIDTypes();
  Batch.prepareLog();
  Batch.getFileNames();
  Batch.makePDF();
  Batch.insertPDF();
  Batch.makeXML();
  Batch.insertXML();
 }
 thisConnection.Close();
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You should remove this. Also, you're still doing all that processing inside your data loop. And you don't need the Batch = null line at the end. It's only being instantiated once each iteration and it gets reinstantiated again anyway, so pointless setting it to null. The issue lies in the subsequent methods. I wouldn't do what you're doing here. I'd do that processing in a separate loop outside of this one, but at least now you can identify a little better where the memory leak is occurring because you have broken out the logic a little.

Comment: @ManoDestra Thanks for your reply. Regarding the program then memory consumption moves up and down as intended - now.
About your statement of processing inside data loop.
How am I to do it if not like this? Thanks in advance.
Please be gentle with me. Im getting beaten up here.

Comment: Two ways of doing this. The way you've done it here is better, as you should get a better sense of the line where the memory consumption makes the program fall over. And from there, you can drill down to find out why. Personally, I would move all those method calls (.setRefnbr(), setIDTypes(), etc) to a second loop. So, loop through the rows of your table, as above, but add each CL_Batch to a List instead. Then loop through that list AFTER this loop and do the method calls there instead. Make sense?

Comment: I politely disagree, ManoDestra:  it *is* "an answer," because it brings *closure* to the topic:  "this, for the record, is how I *fixed* this."  Yes, you could add the same thing the original-post.  But, I definitely like to see a thread (on any forum, anywhere), that "comes to closure."  It reflects:  the initial confusion, the discussion that lead to a solution, *and the solution.*

Comment: @ManoDestra. The program doesn't have any memory problem anymore. The methods you mention actually use the ID number fetched by the loop. If this was not the case I would agree with you.
And of course Batch=null; is unnessecary.

Comment: Yeah, I'd still like to see the solution. I'd still like to know where the problem is/was. And it's still worthwhile wrapping your Connection instantiation in a using, rather than the explicit closure of it :)

Comment: @ManoDestra Unfortunately its a big program and if I was to put it here I'd have to rewrite to hide information.

Comment: The problem would exist in a single line or method though. *shrugs*

Answer (score 3):

This is a stab in the dark since we can't see your code. You're creating PDFs. That often involves either some sort of COM object or a memory stream. Perhaps whatever you're using to create those PDFs isn't getting disposed or cleaned up, so every PDF you create is sitting in memory until you run out. I'd take a closer look at the documentation for whatever component you're using. If something implements `IDisposable` make sure you're disposing it.